# How to sort a dic by values and print

Tags: python, dictionary, key, key-value

so I am a beginner with Python and face one problem. The problem is that I have the following dict:

```
topperformer1 = {"Olivia":19, "Maria":18, "Pedro":15, "Nuno":17, "Julia":19, "Vasco":17, "Carla":18}
```

Now I would like to print the 3 highest grades (value), but if I sort the dict after the value and print it, I only get the value with no key.

I hope you can help me and best regards

Comment: use `collections.Counter`

Answer (score 0):

Use `collections.Counter`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import Counter

topperformer1 = Counter({"Olivia":19, "Maria":18, "Pedro":15, "Nuno":17, "Julia":19, "Vasco":17, "Carla":18})
print(topperformer1.most_common(3))
# --> [('Olivia', 19), ('Julia', 19), ('Maria', 18)]
```